# Assoc-if in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there an "assoc-if" function in the Clojure library? I.e if a value is truthy, update a map with a given key value. I've tried to find something to this effect, but came up lacking.

```
(defn assoc-if
  [m key value]
  (if value (assoc m key value) m))
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If the goal is to avoid repeating `m`, you can use `conj`:

```
(conj m (when value [key value]))
```

...or Clojure 1.5's new threading macros:

```
(-> m
  (cond-> value (assoc key value)))
```

If it's actually important to avoid repeating both the `m` and `value`, you'll have to write your own or reach outside `clojure.core`

Comment: `cond->` is a nice answer here, I think.

Answer (score 12):

There is no build-in `assoc-if` function in Clojure, but you're not the first one who needs it. [Check this link](http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/07/08/assoc-clojure/) with an implementation of `assoc-if` by [ALEX MILLER](http://tech.puredanger.com/author/administrator/):

```
(defn ?assoc
  "Same as assoc, but skip the assoc if v is nil"
  [m & kvs]
  (->> kvs
    (partition 2)
    (filter second)
    flatten
    (apply assoc m)))
```

But, since `flatten` is recursive, it's best to replace it with something which is not (thanks to [kotarak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198935/kotarak) for the hint). Another problem of this implementation is that `(apply assoc m)` will fail on empty list. So, it's best to replace it to:

```
(defn ?assoc
  "Same as assoc, but skip the assoc if v is nil"
  [m & kvs]
  (->> kvs
    (partition 2)
    (filter second)
    (map vec)
    (into m)))
```

Comment: I would replace the `flatten` and `assoc` with `vec` and `into`. `(->> kvs (partition 2) (filter second) (map vec) (into m))`. `flatten` is recursive which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: You're right about `flatten`, but I think it's best simply to replace it with `(apply concat)`.

Comment: But, on second thought, `(apply assoc m)` will fail on empty list and `(into m)` won't.

Comment: Here's a similar answer, but a bit briefer. Appropriate only in the common case where you can pass the kv pairs as a map.

(defn assoc-if
    [m kvs]
  (into m (filter val kvs)))

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`assoc-some`](http://weavejester.github.io/medley/medley.core.html#var-assoc-some) from the [medley](https://github.com/weavejester/medley) library. Battle-tested and widely used.